# EF6: The entity type is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

Our system consists of several assemblies. One of them contains the data access layer that contains a DbContext initialization.

The other assemblies (projects) contains some model classes. In our case a model class is every class decorated by an attribute.

So in the `OnModelCreating` method I do something like:

```
modelBuilder.Types()
            .Where(type => type.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<TablePrefixAttribute>().Any())
            .Configure(config => config.ToTable(GetTableName(config.ClrType)));
```

I hoped the `Types()` method enumerates through all available class types and therefore the where selector will have at least a chance to assign the correct table name to every class I need to do it for.

However, for some types (at least one) I get this error:

```
The entity type ... is not part of the model for the current context
```

If I put a breakpoint to the where method the class causing the error is never in this enumeration. For some other types this works pretty well.

I know I can do something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<...>().ToTable("...")
```

and with this the error disappears, but this is exactly the thing I do not want to do. We are using strict naming conventions and this allows us to obtain table names from class names (simply said). So everytime I decide to add a table and class I do not want to have to register it anywhere.

I am confused about this: what types are listed in `modelBuilder.Types()`? Why there are some classes present while some other not?

If I put a breakpoint inside the `OnModelCreating`, all assemblies that contain some model classes are loaded.

What have I do to get my mapping working?

Comment: When you add an entity class (and table), do you also add a corresponding `DbSet` to your `DbContext`?

Comment: @IvanStoev: No,  we use a soem higher-level abstraction. But on the lowest level, there is a repository with set of generic methods and almost all ot them lead to: `context.Set<T>().someMethod()`. Creating a `DbSet` for each type seems for me similar to registering it in above mentioned way.

Comment: Indeed. However `DbSet` is one of the criteria used by EF to discover entity classes. The second is navigation property of a discovered entity class. The third is `modelBuilder.Entity<>` call. And that's all :) I'm not sure how do you get ever single entity mapped if you don't have any of those.

Comment: @IvanStoev: it appears you are right! My current opinion is that all of the "working classes" are included in the model because of some chain of navigation properties leading from types with `.Entity<>` call somewehre in their assembly.